# Postgres container fails to start due to permissions issue

Tags: postgresql, docker, podman, postgresql-12

I know this issue `FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" has wrong ownership` has been discussed a lot of times. I've gone through a lot of such issues and tried to fix it at my end, but none has been helpful. I will list down more details below.

I am using this docker image : `postgres:12.5-alpine`. I have a NFS mount like `/<nfs_mount_name>/postgres/data`.
Earlier my deployment was using docker-compose through the root user but recently I am trying to shift to using podman.

The NFS mount has permissions `drwxr-xr-x` with the owner being, say user 'A' and group 'B'. Now, I try to run a container using `podman run --user <uid_of_user_A>:<gid_of_user_B> -v <my_nfs_mount>:/var/lib/postgresql/data --env-file .env.pg postgres:12.5-alpine`
The `.env.pg` contains `POSTGRES_USER` and `POSTGRES_PASSWORD`.

The detailed error look like :

```
chmod: /var/lib/postgresql/data: Operation not permitted
chmod: /var/run/postgresql: Operation not permitted

PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization

 FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" has wrong ownership
 HINT:  The server must be started by the user that owns the data directory.
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I think you may be mapping userA to root in the container not "postgres", which is the user the database runs as.